# In Laravel - could not find driver on xampp using ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, xampp

I am working on xampp 7.3 version of PHP.
I am facing the below error.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select `name` from `table` where `id` = e690ddc2-a2b6-4aad-8a73-dab1771c0ea6 limit 1) in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/ProjectFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 669

Also, I have uncommented the pdo_mysql.dll in php.ini file it still giving me an error.
Also, it is working in the windows system but not in Ubuntu16.04.

how can solve this?

Comment: did you manage your database connection in the env file?

Comment: Yes. In my env all DB related settings are well and good.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the necessary packages

`sudo apt-get install php*-mysql`

Then uncomment the MySQL extensions on `php.ini` and restart your server

```sh
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In your project set the correct parameters and in the root of your project run

```php
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: i am using xampp in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: sudo apt-get install php*-mysql. This works for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 by:

1. "Control C" out of the php artisan serve command to stop the application.
2. Stop all the servers running on XAMPP -> (Apache, MySQL and ProFTPD).
3. Enable mysql inside of XAMPP via path $ cd /opt/lampp/etc .
4. $ sudo nano php.ini or open in your choice of text editor. I use PHPStorm.
5. Search for "php_mysql.dll".
6. Removed the ";" in front of ";extension=php_mysql.dll" -> hit save.
7. Back in the terminal -> $ cd.. back one folder into the /opt/lampp.
8. Run $ sudo apt-get install php*-mysql. -> Could take a couple minutes based on your internet connection.
9. After the install is complete -> restart all the XAMPP servers.
10. Run $ php artisan config:cache.
11. Run $ php artisan serve.